# scala: relationship between package and source directory hierarchy

Tags: scala

Does the package declared in the source file must match the directory hierarchy? For example, in source file a/b/c/foo.scala, the package must be a.b.c? If so, why bother to repeat again in the source file? If not, since the source file could declare any package it belongs to, then what's the usage of the directory hierarchy?

And is there some restriction about what could be inside the source file? For example, does the foo.scala could contain public `class foo`, and other classes or functions must be private or package access only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not a requirement, but it the usual behaviour. A file a/b/c/foo.scala could be package x.y.z. I suppose you could say directories manage the way you store your code, and packages manage the way you expose your code.

There are no restrictions about what can be inside the source file (This is different to Java). foo.scala could contain the public class bar, or foo, or both, for example.

Comment: So a/b/c/foo.scala could define `class foobar` in `package a.d.e`? If so, the scala's package is logical concept just like C++ namespace, right? But if so, how could import manage to find a.d.e.foobar (because it does not match the directory structure)? Scan all source files from all possible paths? It does not make sense.